# when is the bounce event phase triggered on a sprite in corona

Tags: lua, box2d, coronasdk

What exactly triggers the "bounce" event (event.phase == "bounce") in corona lua script.  I've added a sprite with physics and it bounces off the ground (on-screen), but this event phase isn't triggered, even though the other event phases are triggered ("began", "ended" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"bounce"` event is triggered when the sprite animation changes direction from forward to backward while playing, it has nothing to do with the physics collision phases which can be `"began"` and `"ended"`.

Comment: thanks royi - so what is it that causes the sprite animation to change from forward to backward (apologies if I'm asking the obvious)?

Comment: ok I see now that the sprite api has methods for playing frames in a set in either forward  or reverse direction - so I guess this is triggered when one of those methods is invoked. (are there any other ways this event might be automatically triggered?)

Comment: It will be triggered if the sprite animation is set to bounce. That is, the animation will play in reverse when it hits the last frame, and so it will "bounce" back and forth. Each time the animation reverses the bounce event will trigger.